# SOQL returns correctly when hard coded but empty with variable

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

This statement:

```
String id = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :cvsData[12]].id;
```

Returns this error (pulls nothing from the object):

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

This Statement:

```
String id = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Name = 'Jane Doe'].id;
```

Completes as expected returning the ID.

**Does anyone know why that would be?**

cvsData[12] definitely contains Jane Doe.

Comment: Is it possible it contains white space or any other characters?

Comment: can you try system.debug for cvsData[12] and see what exact string it outputs ?

Comment: When you are running the two SOQLs are you doing so in the same place? (ie. both in your code, not in the developer console?) just trying to think if you have perhaps introduced a role/permissions/sharing variable to the mix. Otherwise, as @VamsiKrishna said, please debug your array for us to be 10,000% it contains the string correctly!

Comment: A la @PhilB, do a `system.debug(cvsData[12]).length());` to see if the result is 7, and not 8 or more (indicating an unprintable character)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that cvsData is a list of objects, you are trying to check that a name is equal to the object contained in the 13th item of the list.  You need to check if the name equals the name field of the object in the 13th item of the list.  So you need to return the Name value of the record contained in cvsData[12].  Try replacing `cvsData[12]` with `cvsData[12].Name`.

Something like this should work

```
String id = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE Name = :cvsData[12].Name].id;
```

Comment: cvsData is a list of Strings read in from a csv file.